# When is Answer data sent from iOS device?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

I am using Answer from Fabric. My question is clear, when is the data sent from iOS device?

I got [this](https://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/390234-when-is-answers-data-sent-from-an-ios-device) article from Crashlytics, that says if events are sent in batches on iOS when the app is launched or enters the foreground. And I confirmed it in my project.

With debug mode, I know that `Answer` will send event on background (only if I pressed home button).

My question is, is there anyway to send events real time using `Answer`, I mean in foreground? Because I found that in android, we shouldn't go to background first for sending event. This is my `Answer` setting

```
2017-08-22 11:10:50.993 myProject Dev[66680:2305418] [Answers] Answers enabled with settings: {
    "flush_interval_secs" = 300;
    "flush_on_background" = 1;
    "forward_to_google_analytics" = 0;
    "include_purchase_events_in_forwarded_events" = 0;
    "max_byte_size_per_file" = 8000;
    "max_file_count_per_send" = 1;
    "max_pending_send_file_count" = 100;
    "sampling_rate" = 1;
    "track_custom_events" = 1;
    "track_predefined_events" = 1;
    "track_view_controllers" = 0;
    url = "https://e.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/events";
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todd from Fabric here. Right now it's not possible to send these events in real time. This is due to battery and network concerns on your side and scaling concerns on our side. I'll let the team know you are interested!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Answers which is part of the Fabric suit (**Crashlytics** is part of Fabric as well):

[image]

Comment: What do you mean? I am using `Answer` already, and I believe it comes from `Crashlytics` because I only import crashlytics.

Comment: you can send event anytime, viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear

Comment: Indeed, but that answer will transmit its event on background state (user presed home button)